# Excel advanced filter showing identical values

Tags: excel, filter, unique

This should be *extremely* simple, but I'm losing my mind over it. In Excel I use Data/Filter/Advanced and select $B$1:$B$369600 as range. I choose "Unique records only", and I select an empty column for the results. But when I get the results, there are two identical values in the list. Repeatedly.

I've changed columns, changed format, shut the program down and restarted, whatever I could think of, but whatever I do, these two values in the "Unique records" column are identical. Here are two iterations of using the filter. What am I missing? Thanks.

[image]

Longer story: I ran an R script to aggregate data from hundreds of files. There are 4 versions: Winter, Summer, Spring, Fall (four separate Excel files). The data uses the same "character strings as names" in each version, but they are for different seasons. I have 369,600 rows of data, which is 336*20 "takes", as it should be. But to do a double check, I decided to do a "unique values" to make sure that each of the 336 appropriate items are there. Only I get 337. Every time. For every one of the four Excel files. And it seems to be only "10020001" every time. It's maddening.

Comment: Could it be there are some spaces or other "invisible" characters in one of the entries? Without seeing the source data it's kinda hard to troubleshoot, except just throwing ideas out there... Could you maybe include some of the duplicate entries in your question?

Comment: Is there a way to check for invisible characters? I've included the results of two more tries with a different version of the data. It's ONLY these two character strings.

Comment: You could try entering the cells, and see if you can move a space before or after the numbers, but apart from that I am uncertain what would be the best approach. In VBA you could try using the `trim` method on the data before entering it into the cells, which would remove leading and / or trailing whitespaces, I am sure there's something similar in R. This is all assuming ofc, that the issue is what I'm guessing it is. Could very well be something else entirely :-p'

Comment: Use the trim function on all the data, paste special balues and try again.

Comment: One formatted as a number and one as text?  With no alignment set does one align to the right of the cell and the other to the left?

Comment: Thanks guys. I haven't been able to figure it out. But if I do *another* "unique values" on the result of the first one, then it loses the extra. So, that works, FWIW. The trim function did not change anything. And just as a note, the duplicate string always comes out at the top and the very bottom. It only showed up like above when I did a sort.
Weird.